# Accessing I2C slave devices that are specified in Device Tree

Tags: devices, device-tree

I'm trying to communicate with a device over I2C from my BeagleBone Black, and I'm a bit curious as to the device tree's interpretation of I2C.  I see that there are a couple of device nodes within the actual I2C bus node itself, and these are visible in userspace under `/sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-x/`.  But I can't seem to be able to view the status, or query the device like I would be able to with a GPIO device in `/sys/class/gpio`.

I can use SMBus to communicate with the I2C device within a C++ program, but I'm curious as to why some of these built-in devices (like the PMIC) have their own nodes.  Is it for kernel driver reasons?

Comment: No idea how it works on the BeagleBone Black, but in general, you need the adapter entries for `i2cdetect`/`i2cdump`/`i2cset`/`i2cget` etc., and some kernel modules like `eeprom` also make client nodes. As there's no reliable way to detect an i2c client, the kernel can't automatically produce client nodes for each client.

Comment: I see.  After posting the question I went back through some other device's device trees and what seems to be the defining factor between a device that is a 'default' node on the bus and just a random node is whether or not there is a driver for that device.